# Синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите разобрать предложение: "Главное - нужно хорошо загореть"

Answer (score 1):

"Главное" здесь вводное слово, поэтому после него можно поставить и запятую. Ср.: ***И главное, не забудьте приложить аннотированную библиографическую карточку.*** 
Однако и тире после вводного слова ГЛАВНОЕ возможно:

11) Слово главное является вводным в значениях «особенно важно», «особенно существенно»: ***Тему для рассказа можете взять произвольную, но, главное, чтобы было интересно; Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно*** — запятую после союза а поставить нельзя, и для усиления выделения после вводного сочетания поставлено тире; Как крупный учёный, а главное как историк искусства, он пользуется большим авторитетом — в начале обособленного оборота. [здесь](http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

Следовательно, Ваше предложение односоставное, безличное, главный член НУЖНО ЗАГОРЕТЬ. Наречие "хорошо" - обстоятельство.

Answer (score 0):

Это очень похоже на сложное предложение, где "главное" - первое предложение, а "нужно хорошо загореть" - это вторая часть сложного предложения (односоставное, безличное)

Написал данный ответ и засомневался в его правильности. Вспомнил, что есть нечастые случаи, когда один из главных членов может быть выражен целым предложением. Пожалуй, так будет вернее: "главное" - предмет речи, подлежащее, "нужно хорошо загореть" - сказуемое, выраженное односоставным, безличным предложением.